# How can I get rid of the guest login 'feature" of lollipop 5.1.1?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, multi-user

I DO NOT WANT ANYONE BUT ME, to be able to log into my tablet. Can anyone please tell me if/how to "DISABLE" the guest login feature on Lollipop 5.1.1? Lots of chatter out there about how to delete the account but this does not disable it, and is recreated again from the lockout screen at the touch of a finger.

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling it in androids app settings

Comment: How exactly? We're looking for answers that explain fully so that even new users can follow your advice.